# OutputStreamWriter and InputStreamReader for a Socket in Java, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

Using `Socket`s in java,

```
public class Server {

    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static int port = 9876;
    static Socket p1 = null;
    static Socket p2 = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        Thread p1t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("[Server] Waiting for connection");
                    p1 = server.accept();
                    System.out.println("[Server] Client connected");
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p1.getOutputStream()));
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
                    String msg = String.valueOf(in.readLine());
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    out.write(msg);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        p1t.start();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException{
        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), 9876);
        if(socket.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("[Client] Connected");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(in.readLine());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            while(true) {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                out.write(s.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The client is supposed to send a message to the server, and the server is supposed to relay that message back to the client; but either the `BufferedReader` for `Client` and `Server` are not reading anything that is sent, or the `BufferedWriter` for `Client` and `Server` is not sending anything.

I've also tried manually sending text using `out.write("test");` in both classes.

What am I doing wrong in this situation?

Comment: You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a newline to the message, or call `BufferedWriter.newLine()` after the write.

Comment: NB `socket.isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at the point you are testing it. Either the socket was connected by the prior constructor or an exception was thrown. Don't write unnecessary code.

Comment: NB (2) You aren't testing the result of `readLine()` for null, so your thread will spin endlessly and mindlessly when the peer disconnects.

Comment: NB (3) `String.valueOf(in.readLine())` is pointless. Check the result for null: if it is, close and break; and if it isn't it is already a `String`.